# Use lat / long to create polyline that can be passed into DrawPolyline

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, c#

```
public void DrawPolyline(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView activeView)
{
  if(activeView == null) return;
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;

  screenDisplay.StartDrawing(screenDisplay.hDC, (System.Int16)ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache); // Explicit Cast
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRgbColor rgbColor = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RgbColorClass();
  rgbColor.Red = 255;

  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IColor color = rgbColor; // Implicit Cast
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleLineSymbolClass();
  simpleLineSymbol.Color = color;

  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol symbol = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol)simpleLineSymbol; // Explicit Cast
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRubberBand rubberBand = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RubberLineClass();
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry geometry = rubberBand.TrackNew(screenDisplay, symbol);
  screenDisplay.SetSymbol(symbol);
  screenDisplay.DrawPolyline(geometry); //I WANT TO CREATE THIS FROM LAT / LONGs!
  screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();
}
```

The above code snippet works but the problem is I want to create the IGeometry from lat \ longs not from clicking the screen.  How can I create an polyline IGeometry object for the drawPolyline function using standard lat \ long coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this on a form with a mapcontrol.

```
private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Test(axMapControl1.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay, new SimpleLineSymbolClass());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message);
    }
}

public static void Test(IScreenDisplay screenDisp, ILineSymbol lineSym)
{
    IProjectedCoordinateSystem pcs = screenDisp.DisplayTransformation.SpatialReference as IProjectedCoordinateSystem;
    IPolyline polyline = null;
    if (pcs != null)
    {
        polyline = MakePolyline(pcs.GeographicCoordinateSystem);
        polyline.Project(pcs);
    }
    else
    {
        polyline = MakePolyline(new UnknownCoordinateSystemClass());
    }
    if(((IRelationalOperator)polyline).Disjoint(screenDisp.DisplayTransformation.VisibleBounds))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("not within visible bounds");
        return;
    }
    screenDisp.StartDrawing(screenDisp.hDC,(short) esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache );
    screenDisp.SetSymbol((ISymbol)lineSym);
    screenDisp.DrawPolyline(polyline);
    screenDisp.FinishDrawing();
}
public static IPolyline MakePolyline(ISpatialReference sr)
{
    IPointCollection pc = new PolylineClass();
    // deal with legacy COM cruft ...
    object missing = Type.Missing; // (not needed with VB.NET)
    pc.AddPoint(MakePoint(-98.0, 29.0, sr), ref missing, ref missing);
    pc.AddPoint(MakePoint(-97.0, 28.0, sr), ref missing, ref missing);
    pc.AddPoint(MakePoint(-96.0, 27.0, sr), ref missing, ref missing);
    pc.AddPoint(MakePoint(-95.0, 26.0, sr), ref missing, ref missing);

    IPolyline polyline = (IPolyline)pc;
    polyline.SpatialReference = sr;
    return polyline;
}
public static IPoint MakePoint(double x, double y, ISpatialReference sr)
{
    IPoint p = new PointClass();
    p.PutCoords(x, y);
    p.SpatialReference = sr;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: @Kirk Thanks for the code, unfortunately it won't draw the lines.  It doesn't give an error or warning, just no lines.

Comment: In your code, is screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.SpatialReference null?  If not what is screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.SpatialReference.Name?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall It is set to this:"USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic"

Comment: I've edited the code to show how you can project your polyline into the projection used by the screendisplay.

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall thanks again, but I get a COM Error when I try to pass the polyline object into DrawPolyline

Comment: I've edited to code.  It works with mapcontrol v 10.0.